# How to simplify code by Optional or stream or lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, option-type

I have some code that I wanna refactor to simplify it:

```
 public ObjectB doSomethingHere(ObjectA objectA, List<ObjectB> objectBList) {

 boolean emptyObject = objectA == null;
    boolean emptyList = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(objectBList);
    if (emptyObject || emptyList) {
      throw new SomeException("ERROR",
          emptyObject ? null : objectA.getId(),
          emptyList ? 0 : objectBList.size());
    }

    return objectBList
        .stream()        
        .filter(p -> doSomeStuff(p,objectA))
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(ObjectB::getSort))
        .orElse(null);

         }
```

The return part is what the logic should do in case the boolean expression is not true (error handling).

I am guessing this could be handled in 'one shot', something like:

```
Optional.ofNullable(xxx ).orElseThrow(yyyy);
```

How is the best approach to get to this goal?

Comment: I would start by respecting the Java naming conventions. Then I would remove the first argument of the method, since you do  nothing useful with it. Then I would stop using CollectionUtils and checking lists for null: don't pass null colections, ever. If you do, a NullPointereException is the right thing to throw. So the whole first part can in fact be removed, and all is left is the useful part, starting at `return`. `comparingInt()` should be used, and you should consider returning an Optional<ObjectB> instead of null.

Comment: one of the worst uses for `Optional` I have seen. can replace `Optional.ofNullable(object_A).isEmpty()` with `object_A == null`

Comment: The filter should be before the sort, for performance reasons, and the sort + findFirst should be replaced by min().

Comment: changed to code, but still the original question is not answered: Can I simplify the error handling part and the logic part into ONE Optional expression, e.g. something like doLogic.orElse(errorHandling)

Comment: On this, "changed to code, but still the original question is not answered: Can I simplify the error handling part and the logic part into ONE Optional expression, e.g. something like doLogic.orElse(errorHandling)", We can but the thing is that, It will make the code more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your use of the `Optional` really adds anything given you are really just checking if the value is null. So I would suggest:

```
if (objectA == null || objectBList.isEmpty())
```

Your stream operation can be:

```
return objectBList.stream()
    .filter(...)
    .min(...).orElse(null);
```

Comment: CollectionUtils.isEmpty check null and empty. But objectBList.isEmpty() may lead to null pointer exception.

Comment: For the first part Optionial makes no sense, true. I edited the code